# Save the edge detected frames from a video as a video (opencv)

Tags: python, opencv

I Want to save the edge detected frames as a video. I am able to preview the frames of the video but the output video doesn't play.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V')

out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', fourcc, 23.976, (1280,720))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    edges = cv.Canny(frame,50,50)
    out.write(edges)
    cv2.imshow('frame', edges)
    c = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if c & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
```

Answer (score 3):

There are three issues I would like to address.

- 1. You are applying `Canny` to each video frame. What is the output size:

     - ```py
       print(edges.shape)
       (720, 1280)
       ```
     - The dimension `720, 1280` means the frame is a gray-scale value. If the frame is a color image then the dimension will be `(720, 1080, 3)` for each channel R, G, B.
     - Therefore you need to initialize your `VideoWriter` object as a `grey-scale` images.
     - ```py
       out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', fourcc, 23.976, (1280,720), isColor=False)
       ```
- 2. Make sure you are capturing the next frame:

     - ```py
       ret, frame = cap.read()
       if ret:
           edges = cv.Canny(frame,50,50)
           .
           .
       ```
- 3. Make sure your frame are the same dimension with the `VideoWriter` object

  - ```py
    while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        edges = cv2.Canny(frame, 50, 50)
        edges = cv2.resize(edges, (1280, 720))
        out.write(edges)
        .
        .
    ```

Code:

---

```py
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v")

out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', fourcc, 23.976, (1280, 720), isColor=False)

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        edges = cv2.Canny(frame, 50, 50)
        edges = cv2.resize(edges, (1280, 720))
        out.write(edges)
        cv2.imshow('frame', edges)
        c = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if c & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
```